# Downgrading iOS on iPhone helps Wi-Fi and GPS signal?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 6 with the iOS 9.3.2, actually I didn't update my iPhone from an older iOS version. Anyway, I realized that I can't connect to any Wi-Fi network unless I am very close to the router.

Today at McDonald's everyone could connect to the Wi-Fi but I couldn't because I couldn't even find it

In Pokemon GO I can't get any GPS signal while playing and Google Maps is considered slow.

My mom's iPhone 4S connects to the Wi-Fi from very far away.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your phone?  Have you tried "reset network settings"?

Comment: Yes, i tried all the suggestions i found on the internet like these two and much more as setting a new DNS.

Comment: In fact i saw some complains on the internet about wifi signal being weak and all sort of things after ios 9. I guess that the ios 9 has improvements in battery saving so maybe apple reduced the work process of wifi to save some battery.